# SVG image inside of SVG does not scale in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, scale

I'm using an SVG inside of an HTML document, and using an external SVG file inside of said SVG. Like so:

```
<svg class="ipachart" width="500" height="350" viewBox="0 0 500 350" version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <!-- In Firefox 38.0.5, the svg does not scale to fit the SVG. While it's fine in Chrome. -->
    <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtindax1177ewmx/Blank_vowel_trapezoid.svg?dl=1" />

    <!-- Using a PNG, it scales just fine in Firefox -->
    <!-- <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0i764blf4tbc4z/Blank_vowel_trapezoid.png?dl=1" /> -->

</svg>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsyrak/ut4ua980/)

This works fine in Chrome and Safari. (I do not care for IE.)

The problem is that the SVG image does not scale to fit in Firefox (version 38.0.5). Instead of looking like this:

[image: SVG scaling in Chrome]

It looks like this (as if it wasn't scaling at all):

[image: SVG not scaling in Firefox]

If I use a PNG version in place of the SVG, it works like expected. Which makes me think it's a bug.

Should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 4):

No. Because it looks to me like Firefox has the correct behaviour here.

The SVG you are linking to ("Blank_vowel_trapezoid.svg") has no `viewBox` attribute, so it should not / will not be scaled to fit your `<img>` bounds.

If anything you should file bugs against Chrome and IE.

If you want tthe SVG to scale. Add a `viewBox` to its root `<svg>` tag:

```
viewBox="0 0 1000 700"
```

and remove the `width` and `height` attributes.